# Devise: after sign-in redirect back to cancan protected path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan

I am using both Cancan and Devise. I have the following so when cancan errors redirects the page to sign in path:

```
  check_authorization :unless => :devise_controller?
  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    redirect_to new_user_session_path, :alert => exception.message
  end
```

That works well. However, I want to be able to redirect back to that Cancan protected page once user has signed in.

I use the script in the Devise wiki here ([How To: redirect to a specific page on successful sign in](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in#redirect-back-to-current-page-without-oauth-signin)).

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    sign_in_url = url_for(:action => 'new', :controller => 'sessions', :only_path => false, :protocol => 'http')
    if request.referer == sign_in_url
      # this path is used
      super
    else
      stored_location_for(resource) || request.referer || root_path
    end
  end
```

But this will always use the `super` method, which goes to index page. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's late, but I solved it by adding session["user_return_to"] to rescue_from

```
check_authorization :unless => :devise_controller?
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
  session["user_return_to"] = request.fullpath
  redirect_to new_user_session_path, :alert => exception.message
end
```

and removing the after_sign_in_path_for method override. Then Devise will redirect to session["user_return_to"] after sign in.

Comment: A more general solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543503/redirect-back-to-current-page-using-omniauth-and-devise