# redirect back to current page using omniauth and devise

Tags: devise, omniauth

I want to redirect back to current page after oauth signin, and I followed [this Devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in) and did the following:

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    sign_in_url = new_user_session_url
    if request.referer == sign_in_url
      super
    else
      request.env['omniauth.origin'] || stored_location_for(resource) || request.referer || root_path
    end
  end
```

`request.env['omniauth.origin']` is http://www.bubutravel.com/users/sign_in

`stored_location_for(resource)` is nil

`request.referer` is http://openapi.qzone.qq.com/oauth/[omitted] (my provider)

So after my omniauth login, I get redirected to the provider urls again.

Is the wiki outdated? What's the recommended way to do omniauth login redirect to current page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I realized that I should not override `after_sign_in_path_for` as suggested by the wiki. I should just record the path in every request:

```
  before_action :store_current_location, :unless => :devise_controller?
  def store_current_location
    store_location_for(:user, request.url)
  end
```

And the build-in `after_sign_in_path_for` will handle the rest.

Comment: Wow. I have spent weeks trying to figure this one out... so simple. Thank you!

Comment: Small notice: you should store location only for not xhr requests to avoid unknown route exception:
```store_location_for(:user, request.url) unless request.xhr?```