# Failing to understand Devise after sign in redirect with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, devise

I'm a bit of a rails/devise newbie and I have done months of searching on this and haven't found a solution.

What I'm trying to do seems simple: Redirect a user to the previous page after a successful sign in event using Rails and the Devise gem (v 3.2.3), but instead all of my sign in redirects are going to the root path. It's annoying because if I send someone a link to a specific page within which they have to authenticate, it redirects them to the home page again.

I'm aware that other questions on SO ask this, but I think I'm asking a higher level question about the code in Devise.

So my overall question is this: Is my understanding of the problem and solution correct? In order to solve, I need to:

- Store the users previous page from their session
- Redirect to that location in the after_sign_in_path function

I'm looking at some code comments in Devise **lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb** on line 177:

```
# The default url to be used after signing in. This is used by all Devise
  # controllers and you can overwrite it in your ApplicationController to
  # provide a custom hook for a custom resource.
  #
  # By default, it first tries to find a valid resource_return_to key in the
  # session, then it fallbacks to resource_root_path, otherwise it uses the
  # root path. For a user scope, you can define the default url in
  # the following way:
```

Then on line 204 of that file:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  stored_location_for(resource_or_scope) || signed_in_root_path(resource_or_scope)
end
```

which lead me to the stored_location_for method in **store_location.rb**:

```
def stored_location_for(resource_or_scope)
  session_key = stored_location_key_for(resource_or_scope)
  if is_navigational_format?
    session.delete(session_key)
  else
    session[session_key]
  end
end
```

So code in **sessions#create** is being called when a new user logs in:

```
# POST /resource/sign_in
def create
  self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
  set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_flashing_format?
  sign_in(resource_name, resource)
  yield resource if block_given?
  respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
end
```

And that calls `after_sign_in_path_for(resource)` which I pasted above. My question is this: Is this everything I need to be able to redirect someone to the previous page instead of the root path? Is there something missing that I need to add? How can I test that after_sign_in_path_for(resource) is not nil? Anyone else have experience with this?

Just for reference here is my **routes** file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'orders/index'
  resources "orders", :controller => :my_orders, :as => :orders
  get 'faq/index'
  resources "faq", :controller => :faq, :as => :faq
  get 'guidelines/index'
  resources "guidelines", :controller => :guidelines, :as => :guidelines
  get 'terms_of_use/index'
  resources "terms-of-use", :controller => :terms_of_use, :as => :terms_of_use
  get 'privacy_policy/index'
  resources "privacy-policy", :controller => :privacy_policy, :as => :privacy_policy

  # This line mounts Spree's routes at the root of your application.
  # This means, any requests to URLs such as /products, will go to Spree::ProductsController.
  # If you would like to change where this engine is mounted, simply change the :at option to something different.
  #
  # We ask that you don't use the :as option here, as Spree relies on it being the default of "spree"
  mount Spree::Core::Engine, :at => '/store'

# Need to adjust this for FB authentication
  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'users/registrations', passwords: 'users/passwords' }

  devise_scope :user do
    get 'register', to: 'devise/registrations#new', as: :register
    get 'signin', to: 'devise/sessions#new', as: :signin
    get 'logout', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: :logout
    get 'edit', to: 'devise/registrations#edit', as: :edit
    put "update" => 'devise/registrations#update', as: :updateprofile
  end

  get 'welcome/index'

  get '/sell' => 'sell#index'

  get '/:id', to: 'profiles#show', as: :profile

  root 'welcome#index'

  # for setting up the stripe webhook
  post '/hooks/stripe' => 'hooks#stripe'


end
```

I will happily reveal more of my code if it's useful.

Thank you in advance,

- Brandon

***EDIT***
Did some more digging to narrow this down. I commented out a lot of the code in store_location.rb to see what the session key. Commented out the if/else statement since it was a navigational format, apparently (what does that mean anyway?):

```
  def stored_location_for(resource_or_scope)
    session_key = stored_location_key_for(resource_or_scope)
    puts "session_key = #{session_key}"
    puts "session = #{session}"
    puts "session[session_key] = #{session[session_key]}"
    # if is_navigational_format?
    #   puts "is navigational"
    #   session.delete(session_key)
    # else
    #   puts "is not navigational"
    puts "session[session_key] = #{session[session_key]}"
    session[session_key]
    # end
  end
```

and I added some put statements in this method which is bound to session_key.

```
  def stored_location_key_for(resource_or_scope)
    scope = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource_or_scope)
    "#{scope}_return_to"
  end
```

Here's the output in the command line:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-03 22:34:31 -0500
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"/Xjy/neoPX2nGqpz+FtACjtTx4nnkhiRuVln44Zi4qI=", "user"=>{"email"=>"brandon.a.hay@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."email" = 'brandon.a.hay@gmail.com'  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "current_sign_in_at" = ?, "last_sign_in_at" = ?, "sign_in_count" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = 7  [["current_sign_in_at", "2015-05-04 03:34:31.179646"], ["last_sign_in_at", "2015-05-04 03:32:08.608830"], ["sign_in_count", 65], ["updated_at", "2015-05-04 03:34:31.181312"]]
  Spree::Role Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "spree_roles".* FROM "spree_roles"  WHERE "spree_roles"."name" = 'admin' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "spree_roles_users" ("role_id", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?)  [["role_id", 1], ["user_id", 7]]
   (1.5ms)  commit transaction
session_key = user_return_to
session = #<ActionDispatch::Request::Session:0x007fc7c4af34b0>
session[session_key] =
stored location =
session_key = user_return_to
session = #<ActionDispatch::Request::Session:0x007fc7c4af34b0>
session[session_key] =
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
```

So, stored_location_key_for returns the user class and binds that to the scope. session_key returns "user_return_to", session returns an action dispatch request session, and session[session_key] is nil. Can someone help make sense of this to me?

Comment: Maybe spree is defining it's own after_sign_in_path method. Easy way to debug it is to add some puts statements in devise code, reload rails server and check what value this method returns.

Comment: Don't have time to read thoroughly, but I am guessing this can help http://stackoverflow.com/a/26544722/474597

Comment: Thanks for noticing Spree Michal. I should have mentioned that. I looked through their code and it doesn't appear to have any influence of the sign in redirect process.

Comment: @Michal, I found out some more stuff regarding devise and the stored_location_for method. Could you respond the edits in my question above? Will post in 2 minutes...

Comment: And what is your spree version?

Comment: Spree version = 2-4 stable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer from this post solved my problem: [redirect back to current page using omniauth and devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543503/redirect-back-to-current-page-using-omniauth-and-devise/26544722#26544722)

I had to add a store location call back in my application controller:

```
#application_controller.rb
before_filter :store_current_location, :unless => :devise_controller?

def store_current_location
  store_location_for(:user, request.url)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect routes in your controller, like this

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
    def index
        if user_signed_in?
            redirect_to blogs_index_path
        end
    end
end
```

go to terminal and type rake routes and find the path you want and redirect it there. hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like attempted location is never stored or stored in a wrong place. Look at this code https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v3.2.3/lib/devise/failure_app.rb

Failure app is always called when authentication fails. You can see that on line 57 it stores accessed uri. You can try to debug in this place.

I can think of few reasons why this doesn't work:

- you are using different failure app which doesn't store location
- session key is incorrect in failure app
- there is some code that clears stored location

If you cannot find what problem causes this you can try to copy code from devise failure app to your application controller. Use prepend_before_filter to store location before any other before_filters.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a shot. Also looking into this  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26544722/474597)  from one of the previous comments.

Comment: The link here worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543503/redirect-back-to-current-page-using-omniauth-and-devise/26544722#26544722